# C++ Trying to make a game, having trouble returning a function's value inside a while loop. Would appreciate assistance

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int playerhealth = 100;
int enemyhealth = 100;
default_random_engine random(time(NULL));
uniform_real_distribution<float> chance(0.0, 1.0);
float hit = chance(random);
int playerturn() {
    if (hit > 0.5) {
        enemyhealth -= 10;
        return enemyhealth;     

    }
}
int enemyturn() {
    if (hit > 0.5) {
        playerhealth -= 10;
        return playerhealth;
    }
}
int main() {
    cout << "simulating combat" << endl;
    while ((enemyhealth > 0) && (playerhealth > 0)) {
        playerturn();
        cout << " enemy" << enemyhealth << endl;
        enemyturn();
        cout << "player"<<playerhealth << endl;
        //the values inside the playerturn and enemy turn don't change

    }

}
```

I think the my code is self explanatory. I'm trying to iterate through the while loop, having enemyhealth and playerhealth decrease after every successful attack by 10, but but it doesn't change. How can I fix that? also, side question, are there any things I can do to improve my code?

Comment: You're not recalculating the chance each time through the loop, you're just re-using the same value calculated at start-up each time.

Comment: Did you check the value of hit?

Comment: `using namespace std;` - please kick out the evil!

Comment: The question "are there any things I can do to improve my code" seems too broad.

Comment: If the conditions in the functions are false, you're not returning anything. If you change the calling code to actually *use* the returned value then you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 5):

```
float hit = chance(random);
```

This call to `chance` will only ever happen once, so `hit` only ever has one value. It's like rolling a die once at the beginning of the game and then basing every attack on that roll. Instead, you should roll it at the beginning of each player's turn.

Comment: "rolling die" I would rather not... :D

Comment: That's a good way to improve my code, but my main problem is still unsolved. I'm trying to return the value inside function playerturn() and enemyturn(), but it doesn't return therefor my program runs forever and it doesn't decrease so it can break the condition of the while loop to exit.

Comment: @momomo Are you sure? The `return`s are unnecessary because you are modifying global variables and are not doing anything with the return value anyway. You could just make those functions return `void`. As you have it, your code will run forever if your call to chance returns a value less than 0.5.

Comment: I'm uhh...not really following you, sorry for being a complete noob.

Comment: @momomo Do you see how `playerhealth` and `enemyhealth` are declared outside of your functions? That means they're global. All functions can see those integers. When you do `playerhealth -= 10;` inside your function, you are decreasing the global `playerhealth`. Inside `main`, you print this global `playerhealth`, so if it has been decreased, the new value will be printed.

Comment: And that's what I'm aiming for, but it does not decrease.